# nest.js @Post setting the content-type of the response

Tags: typescript, api, post, content-type, nestjs

I am trying to implement a POST endpoint to my API, which returns an HTML string when called at.

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
import { Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
@Controller()
export class MyController {
    @Post('/endpoint')
    public create(): string {
        return `
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            …
            </html>`;
    }
}
```

How can I tell the POST endpoint to send the correct content-type together with it's response? I've searched all documentations but was not able to find anything helpful for me.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I was able to find the answer myself. I just added the `@Header` decorator just behind the `@Post` decorator:

```ts
import { Header } from '@nestjs/common'

@Post('/endpoint')
@Header('content-type', 'text/html')
public create(): string {
  //
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option (assuming Express is used), is to specify content type when sending the response. This will allow you to conditionally return JSON (or other response types) while processing the request:

```
import { Response } from 'express';

@Post('/endpoint')
public create(@Res() res: Response): string {
    // ...
    if (error) {
        return res.status(404).json({message: 'image not found'});
    }
    // ...
    return res.status(200).contentType('text/html').send(document);
}
```